# Upsell in Cart in Shopify

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-template

So the problem arises that I coded an upsell for my shopify store but now the issue is that, The product is getting added in the quick-cart (Sliding cart), but I wanted to add that in my Quick-cart section, where now the problem is in custom.js the ajax code can send data to quick-cart, but if I call the ajax code in the quick cart only then, it will be redirected to main-cart, but I wanted that the code behave same in the quick-cart only.

```
    {% form 'product', products, data-product-form: '', class: 'product-handle', id:"upsell-form" %}
      <h1 style="text-align: center">Recommended Product</h1>
    <div class="upsell-div" style="display: flex">

      <a href="{{ product.url }}">
          <img style=" width: 100px;
          height: 100px; 
          object-fit: cover; 
          margin-right: 10px;" src="{{ products | img_url: '200x200' }}" alt="{{ products.title }}">
          </a>
        <div class="upsell-details" style=" line-height: 1;">
          <span class="meta">
          <h3 style="text-align: left;" href="{{ products.url }}">{{ products.title }}</h3> 
          <p style="text-align: left;">{{ products.price | money }}</p>
          <iframe name="dummyframe" id="dummyframe" style="display: none;"></iframe>

<input name="id" value="{{ products.variants.first.id }}" type="hidden" />
<button
       type="submit"
       class="bttn bttn--full mb2 button upsell-add-button {% if block.settings.show_dynamic_checkout %}bttn--secondary{% endif %} "
       data-add-button
       data-lang-available="{{ 'products.product.add_to_cart' | t }}"
       data-lang-sold-out="{{ 'products.product.sold_out' | t }}"
>
<span class="bttn__spinner">
{% render 'icon-spinner' %}
</span>

<span data-add-button-text class="add-btn-txt-cstm">
{{ 'products.product.add_to_cart' | t }} - {{ products.variants.first.price | money }}
</span>
</button>
          </span>
      </div>
 
</div>
{% endform %}
   {% endfor %}
  </div>
```

This code is the upsell code.
The AJAX code of my custom.js

```
 const cartButtonHandler = () => {
      $("[data-add-button]").on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let current_elem = $(this);
        let id = $("[data-available-variant-id]").val();
        let quantity = "";
        quantity = $("#Quantity").val();

        if (typeof quantity === 'undefined') {
          quantity = 1;
        }
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: '/cart/add.js',
          data: {
            quantity: quantity,
            id: id
          },
          dataType: 'json',
          beforeSend: function () {
            $(".bttn__spinner").show();
          },
          success: function (data) {
            $(".bttn__spinner").hide();
            quantityUpdate();
            $(".quick-cart__items").load(" .quick-cart__items>*", '');
            appendQuickCart();
            setTimeout(() => {
              $(".quick-cart__icon").eq(0).trigger("click");
              $("#custom_heading_cart").load(" #custom_heading_cart");
            }, 1000);
          },
          error: function (xhr) {
            $(".bttn__spinner").hide();
            console.log("Error occured.please try again", xhr.statusText + xhr.responseText);
            if(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).message == 'Cart Error'){
              current_elem.find('.add-btn-txt-cstm').text('We have reached our stock limit')
            }
            
          }
        });
      });
    };

    cartButtonHandler();
```

Please anyone know how to tackle it.

I expect that the upsell should be working in Quick-cart only without redirecting to main cart.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few modifications you can make to apply this functionality. First, we should prevent the default form submission, so the page doesn't reload / interfere with the AJAX:

```
e.preventDefault();
```

Then we'll grab the product variant ID and add a quantity fall back:

```
let id = current_elem.closest('form').find('input[name="id"]').val();

if (typeof quantity === 'undefined' || !quantity) {
    quantity = 1;
}
```

Here is the updated code:

```
const cartButtonHandler = () => {
    $("[data-add-button]").on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // prevent the default form submission

        let current_elem = $(this);
        
        // Grab the ID from the hidden input inside the form related to the clicked button.
        let id = current_elem.closest('form').find('input[name="id"]').val();
        
        let quantity = $("#Quantity").val();
        if (typeof quantity === 'undefined' || !quantity) {
            quantity = 1;
        }

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/cart/add.js',
            data: {
                quantity: quantity,
                id: id
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function () {
                $(".bttn__spinner").show();
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $(".bttn__spinner").hide();
                quantityUpdate();
                $(".quick-cart__items").load(" .quick-cart__items>*", '');
                appendQuickCart();
                setTimeout(() => {
                    $(".quick-cart__icon").eq(0).trigger("click");
                    $("#custom_heading_cart").load(" #custom_heading_cart");
                }, 1000);
            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                $(".bttn__spinner").hide();
                console.log("Error occurred. Please try again", xhr.statusText + xhr.responseText);
                if(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).message == 'Cart Error'){
                    current_elem.find('.add-btn-txt-cstm').text('We have reached our stock limit')
                }
            }
        });
    });
};

cartButtonHandler();
```

Now this should prevent any unintended form submission that could redirect/refresh the page, grab the correct variant ID and make sure a default quantity is set if none is provided. Hope this helps!

Comment: What Id I have to give in the let id = current_elem.closest('form').find('input[name="id"]').val(); I am not able to figure out?

Comment: The id in that line is automatically fetched from the hidden input field inside the form associated with the button you clicked. You don't need to manually provide any ID, the code retrieves it from the form's input for you